# Sum of Lengths of Non-Overlapping SubArrays

Tags: arrays, overlapping, sub-array

Given an array `arr[]` of ***N elements***, the task is to find the maximum sum of lengths of all non-overlapping subarrays with K as the maximum element in the subarray.

Example 1:

```
Input: N = 9, K = 4
arr[] = {2, 1, 4, 9, 2, 3, 8, 3, 4} 
Output: 5
Explanation: {2, 1, 4} => Length = 3
             {3, 4} => Length = 2
             So, 3 + 2 = 5 is the answer.
```

`{2, 1, 4, 9, 2, 3, 8, 3, 4}`  in this array we can have `{2,1,4}`, `{2,3}` and `{3,4 }` subarray which satisfies the required condition but second subarray is not mentioned. Please tell me Why?

Comment: This isn't a code based problem, but poorly worded constraints. At best answers will be opinion based.

Comment: If somebody has answer please reply.